# My cloud services have too much latency for database requests

Tags: cloud, database-connection, latency

I am the developer of a REST API with node.js and MySQL (pool connection) for a SAAS project. The software has not much traffic but is data-intensive. So I have oprations with thousands of requests in loops when fetching big datasets or import datasets. This is no problem in my local environment or with dedicated servers I am familiar with. Here I have a latency around 1 - 2 ms for a database request. But the company is hosting the REST API at Heroku and the database at Scaleway. I have latency from 20ms (read) up to 60ms (write) for a single request what brings me to timeouts for some operations.
Are there possibilities to fix the problem with cloud services or serverless? Are container solutions a possibility? For privacy reasons the Database has to be located anywhere in europe. Thanks for your help!

I did setup the database connections from node with sequelize pool connection.

Comment: If your backend and database are far apart requests take time. Solution: bring them closer together. How you do that depends entirely on the used services and your requirements.